# Recursively search directories and their subdirectories for images and videos, except system or locked folders

Tags: c#, performance

Search directories and their subdirectories for images and videos, except:

- Windows system folders,
- locked folders,
- and folders selected by me. For example, as a developer I have dozens of Visual Studio folders with folders named bin and debug in them.

The goal was to write the program in a smart way. That's why I work with a List(of IO.FileInfo), which contains the files to be copied; and a List(of String), which contains the folder names that should not be searched. There is another List(of String); this one contains the allowed file extensions. The function calls itself again, so there is a List(Of IO.DirectoryInfo) that contains the folders that are already known. I also work with folder attributes so that the program doesn't try to search locked folders. That would throw an UnauthorizedAccessException and crash the program.

By the way: Sorting the two lists “allowedExtensions” and “iDontWant” was for me only for clarity when debugging.

Is there anything to improve here?

[image: GUI]

[image: Output window]

**StringNaturalSortComparer.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Backup
{
    public class StringNaturalSortComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

**FormMain.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Backup
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        private readonly List<System.IO.FileInfo> ListOfFilesToBeCopied = new List<System.IO.FileInfo>();
        private readonly List<System.IO.DirectoryInfo> IAlreadyKnow = new List<System.IO.DirectoryInfo>();
        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private readonly System.Globalization.CultureInfo Deu = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");

        private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IAlreadyKnow.Clear();
            ListOfFilesToBeCopied.Clear();
            SearchDirectories(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)));
            long totalSizeInBytes = 0L;

            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in ListOfFilesToBeCopied)
            {
                totalSizeInBytes += fi.Length;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("");
            Debug.WriteLine($"{ListOfFilesToBeCopied.Count} Files.");
            Debug.WriteLine($"{Math.Round((double)totalSizeInBytes / 1024.0, 0).ToString(Deu)} KB");
            Debug.WriteLine($"{Math.Round((double)totalSizeInBytes / Math.Pow(1024.0, 2), 1).ToString(Deu)} MB");
            Debug.WriteLine($"{Math.Round((double)totalSizeInBytes / Math.Pow(1024.0, 3), 1).ToString(Deu)} GB");
        }

        private void SearchDirectories(System.IO.DirectoryInfo source)
        {
            List<string> allowedExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".png", ".webp" };
            if (CheckBoxV.Checked)
            {
                allowedExtensions.AddRange(new string[] { ".avi", ".mp4" });
            }
            allowedExtensions = allowedExtensions.OrderBy(o => o, new StringNaturalSortComparer()).ToList();

            List<string> iDontWant = new List<string> {
".config",
".dotnet",
".FreeYouTubeToMP3Converter",
".nuget",
".QtWebEngineProcess",
".templateengine",
".thumbnails",
".vscode",
"3D Objects",
"ansel",
"Anwendungsdaten",
"AppData",
"Contacts",
"Cookies",
"Druckumgebung",
"Eigene Dateien",
"Favorites",
"Links",
"Lokale Einstellungen",
"Netzwerkumgebung",
"OneDrive",
"Recent",
"Saved Games",
"Searches",
"SendTo",
"source",
"Startmenü",
"Vorlagen",
"InventoryApp",
".picasaoriginals",
".vs",
"v16",
"bin",
"Release",
"My Project",
"obj",
"Debug",
"TempPE",
"packages",
"lib",
"Benutzerdefinierte Office-Vorlagen",
"Custom Office Templates",
"OneNote_RecycleBin",
"config",
"Logs",
"TraceLogFiles"
};

            iDontWant = iDontWant.OrderBy(o => o, new StringNaturalSortComparer()).ToList();

            // Check for folders that are in the source folder and view their files.
            int _9238 = (int)(System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden | System.IO.FileAttributes.ReparsePoint | System.IO.FileAttributes.NotContentIndexed | System.IO.FileAttributes.System | System.IO.FileAttributes.Directory);
            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo subdirectory in source.GetDirectories())
            {
                // If that's a folder I don't want, or that's a system folder, move on to the next one!
                if (iDontWant.Contains(subdirectory.Name) || (int)subdirectory.Attributes == _9238 || IAlreadyKnow.Contains(subdirectory))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Unfortunately, there are many system folders that are locked for programmes. I cannot know all of them, especially their foreign names. Therefore, in addition to the “iDontWant” list, there is this try-catch block.
                try
                {
                    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in subdirectory.GetFiles())
                    {
                        if (allowedExtensions.Contains(fi.Extension.ToLower(Deu)) && !ListOfFilesToBeCopied.Contains(fi))
                        {
                            ListOfFilesToBeCopied.Add(fi);
                        }
                    }
                    IAlreadyKnow.Add(subdirectory);
                    SearchDirectories(subdirectory);
                }
                catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you recreate and sort the `iDontWant` collection every time when someone calls the `SearchDirectories` method?

Comment: @PeterCsala So far, there is no reason for me to declare this list global. I don't need it anywhere else. The sorting was for me only for debugging purposes, so when I hover the over the list that I see what is in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first target the comment

> Why do you recreate and sort the iDontWant collection every time when someone calls the SearchDirectories method? –
> Peter Csala
> yesterday

and let us only check about **recreation** of the `List<string> iDontWant`:

- on my Win10-PC the C:\Windows folder contains 142654 folders
- althougth in your app you only search inside the `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` folder on my Win10-PC this folder contains 16169 subfolders.

Because you search through each subfolder which isn't contained in the `iDontWant` list I would assume you will search through 10000 folders which means the said list will be created 10000 times. This leads to the `allowedExtensions` which in best case only contains 5 items, but there just isn't a good reason to recreate that list either  each time the method is called.

You state as answer to the comment

> So far, there is no reason for me to declare this list global. I don't need it anywhere else.

which is a valid point, but how about using an overloaded method like so

```
private void SearchDirectories(System.IO.DirectoryInfo source, List<string> allowedExtensions, List<string> excludedFolderNames)
{
    int _9238 = (int)(System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden | System.IO.FileAttributes.ReparsePoint | System.IO.FileAttributes.NotContentIndexed | System.IO.FileAttributes.System | System.IO.FileAttributes.Directory);
    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo subdirectory in source.GetDirectories())
    {

        // If that's a folder I don't want, or that's a system folder, move on to the next one!
        if (excludedFolderNames.Contains(subdirectory.Name) || (int)subdirectory.Attributes == _9238 || IAlreadyKnow.Contains(subdirectory))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Unfortunately, there are many system folders that are locked for programmes. I cannot know all of them, especially their foreign names. Therefore, in addition to the “iDontWant” list, there is this try-catch block.
        try
        {
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in subdirectory.GetFiles())
            {
                if (allowedExtensions.Contains(fi.Extension.ToLower(Deu)) && !ListOfFilesToBeCopied.Contains(fi))
                {
                    ListOfFilesToBeCopied.Add(fi);
                }
            }
            IAlreadyKnow.Add(subdirectory);
            SearchDirectories(subdirectory, allowedExtensions, excludedFolderNames);
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

which you would call like

```
private void SearchDirectories(System.IO.DirectoryInfo source)
{
    List<string> allowedExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".png", ".webp" };
    if (CheckBoxV.Checked)
    {
        allowedExtensions.AddRange(new string[] { ".avi", ".mp4" });
    }
    allowedExtensions = allowedExtensions.OrderBy(o => o, new StringNaturalSortComparer()).ToList();

    List<string> iDontWant = new List<string> {

".config",
".dotnet",
".FreeYouTubeToMP3Converter",
".nuget",
".QtWebEngineProcess",
".templateengine",
".thumbnails",
".vscode",
"3D Objects",
"ansel",
"Anwendungsdaten",
"AppData",
"Contacts",
"Cookies",
"Druckumgebung",
"Eigene Dateien",
"Favorites",
"Links",
"Lokale Einstellungen",
"Netzwerkumgebung",
"OneDrive",
"Recent",
"Saved Games",
"Searches",
"SendTo",
"source",
"Startmenü",
"Vorlagen",
"InventoryApp",
".picasaoriginals",
".vs",
"v16",
"bin",
"Release",
"My Project",
"obj",
"Debug",
"TempPE",
"packages",
"lib",
"Benutzerdefinierte Office-Vorlagen",
"Custom Office Templates",
"OneNote_RecycleBin",
"config",
"Logs",
"TraceLogFiles"
};

    iDontWant = iDontWant.OrderBy(o => o, new StringNaturalSortComparer()).ToList();
    SearchDirectories(source, allowedExtensions, iDontWant);

}
```

But wait, in the current state of your code, we can do better....

- the code in question can never reach the same folder twice which means that you don't need to know which subfolder had been processed. In the same way the code won't reach the same file twice. This means you can get rid of `IAlreadyKnow` and the call to `ListOfFilesToBeCopied.Contains(fi)`.
- we should pass the `FileAttributes` as well because there is no need to create them always. We don't need them to be converted to an `int` either.
- by extracting the check for valid files and folders to separate methods the whole code gets easier to read.
- instead of using `GetFiles()` and `GetDirectories()` we could use `EnumerateFiles` and `EnumerateDirectories`.
- we could take advantage of `List<T>.AddRange()`

In addition, you should extract the searching code to a separate class to separate UI and logic.

Summing up would look like so

```
private bool IsValidDirectory(System.IO.DirectoryInfo subdirectory, System.IO.FileAttributes attribute, List<string> excludedFolderNames)
{
    return !excludedFolderNames.Contains(subdirectory.Name) && subdirectory.Attributes != attribute;
}
private bool IsValidFile(System.IO.FileInfo file, List<string> allowedExtensions)
{
    return allowedExtensions.Contains(file.Extension.ToLower(Deu));
}
private void SearchDirectories(System.IO.DirectoryInfo source, List<string> allowedExtensions, System.IO.FileAttributes allowedAttributes, List<string> excludedFolderNames)
{


    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo subdirectory in source.EnumerateDirectories()
                                                           .Where(d => IsValidDirectory(d, allowedAttributes, excludedFolderNames)))
    {
        // Unfortunately, there are many system folders that are locked for programmes. I cannot know all of them, especially their foreign names. Therefore, in addition to the “iDontWant” list, there is this try-catch block.
        try
        {
            ListOfFilesToBeCopied.AddRange(subdirectory.EnumerateFiles().Where(f => IsValidFile(f, allowedExtensions)));
            SearchDirectories(subdirectory, allowedExtensions, allowedAttributes, excludedFolderNames);
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And would be called like

```
System.IO.FileAttributes allowedAttributes = (System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden | System.IO.FileAttributes.ReparsePoint | System.IO.FileAttributes.NotContentIndexed | System.IO.FileAttributes.System | System.IO.FileAttributes.Directory);
SearchDirectories(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)), allowedExtensions, allowedAttributes, iDontWant);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think it's especially great that the function could be shortened like this, since you used LINQ, namely `EnumerateDirectories().Where` and `EnumerateFiles().Where` in conjunction with the two new bool functions. You are right about the unnecessary recreation of the `excludedFolderNames` list (formerly `iDonWant`)....